# upload file through signed url to google cloud storage with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I try to upload files to my Google Cloud Storage using signed urls.

- I have set the CORS parameters on my bucket using *gsutil*
- the browser sends an ajax request to the Django backend to get a signed url
- the Django backend make a request to *GCS* in order to create a signed url
- the signed url is sent back to the browser.
- I try to upload a video file (Content Type="video/mp4") to *GCS* using this signed url in an *ajax*
- The request to *GCS* return status code 200
- last but not least, an empty file is created in my bucket...

**how to prevent of uploading an empty file ?**
I do not see nor in the GCS documentation, nor on stackoverflow what is wrong

```
function ajaxSendToStorage(url, file, row){
  $.ajax({
    method: 'PUT',
    dataType: "xml",
    contentType: file.type,
    crossDomain: true,
    data: file,
    url: url,
    beforeSend: function (request){
        request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", 'multipart/formdata; charset=UTF-8');
    },
    success: function(data) {
        storageLoadComplete(row)
    },
    complete: function() {
        // do something when complete
    },
  });
}
```

...and here is what I get in console logs:

#### General

**Request URL:** https://test-dev-flowker.storage.googleapis.com/media/uploads/FR/flowker_e6938cf0/2020/3/full_9140a387-0595-4ea7-9fdd-f5d525e57515.mp4?X-Goog-Algorithm=GOOG4-RSA-SHA256&X-Goog-Credential=dev-storage%40brilliant-tower-264412.iam.gserviceaccount.com%2F20200317%2Fauto%2Fstorage%2Fgoog4_request&X-Goog-Date=20200317T105745Z&X-Goog-Expires=1800&X-Goog-SignedHeaders=host&x-goog-signature=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
**Request Method:** PUT
**Status Code:** 200 
**Remote Address:** [2a00:1450:4007:80c::2010]:443
**Referrer Policy:** no-referrer-when-downgrade

#### Response Headers

**access-control-allow-origin:** *
**access-control-expose-headers:** *, Content-Length, Content-Type, Date, Server, Transfer-Encoding, X-GUploader-UploadID, X-Google-Trace
**alt-svc:** quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43",h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q049=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q048=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000
**content-length:** 0
**content-type:** text/html; charset=UTF-8
**date:** Tue, 17 Mar 2020 10:57:46 GMT
**etag:** "d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e"
**server:** UploadServer
**status:** **200**
**x-goog-generation:** 1584442666113578
**x-goog-hash:** crc32c=AAAAAA==
**x-goog-hash:** md5=1B2M2Y8AsgTpgAmY7PhCfg==
**x-goog-metageneration:** 1
**x-goog-stored-content-encoding:** identity
**x-goog-stored-content-length:** 0
**x-guploader-uploadid:** AEnB2UpD_E6yxot73qDMfKu6kM34PPiK7kEM4VytfmZfY6q70dJxBzWs_3y8Lkimwg_ztFTK0Vuoz-V0G_wZlKqah1cax9kJrQ

#### Request Headers

**:authority:** test-dev-flowker.storage.googleapis.com
**:method:** PUT
**:path:** /media/uploads/FR/flowker_e6938cf0/2020/3/full_9140a387-0595-4ea7-9fdd-f5d525e57515.mp4?X-Goog-Algorithm=GOOG4-RSA-SHA256&X-Goog-Credential=dev-storage%40brilliant-tower-264412.iam.gserviceaccount.com%2F20200317%2Fauto%2Fstorage%2Fgoog4_request&X-Goog-Date=20200317T105745Z&X-Goog-Expires=1800&X-Goog-SignedHeaders=host&x-goog-signature=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
**:scheme:** https
**accept:** application/xml, text/xml, */*; q=0.01
**accept-encoding:** gzip, deflate, br
**accept-language:** fr-FR,fr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
**content-length:** 0
**origin:** http://localhost:8000
**referer:** http://localhost:8000/fr/
**sec-fetch-dest:** empty
**sec-fetch-mode:** cors
**sec-fetch-site:** cross-site
**user-agent:** Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.132 Mobile Safari/537.36
**x-client-data:** CKW1yQEIkLbJAQiktskBCKmdygEIt6rKAQjLrsoBCNCvygEIvLDKAQiXtcoBCJu1ygEI7bXKAQiOusoBCOu7ygEIr73KAQ==

#### Query String Parameters

**X-Goog-Algorithm:** GOOG4-RSA-SHA256
**X-Goog-Credential:** dev-storage@sublime-covid-264412.iam.gserviceaccount.com/20200317/auto/storage/goog4_request
**X-Goog-Date:** 20200317T105745Z
**X-Goog-Expires:** 1800
**X-Goog-SignedHeaders:** host
**x-goog-signature:** 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

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ok. I solved it. I didn't bind the file correctly and I was sending a null object. It's now working, but I had to add a line as I get an '**illegal invocation error**'.
I had to add `processData: false,` and it's now working perfectly.

here is the code; if it could helps...

```
function ajaxSendToStorage(url, uuid, row){
var file = getFileById(uuid);
$.ajax({
    method: "PUT",
    contentType: file.type,
    processData: false,
    dataType: "xml",
    crossDomain: true,
    data: file,
    url: url,
    beforeSend: function (request){
        request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", 'multipart/formdata; charset=UTF-8');
    },
    success: function(data) {
        storageLoadComplete(row)
    },
    complete: function() {
        var a = 1;
    },

});
```

}

Comment: it's only upload the file but video is not streaming